libgtkgl2.0-dev: package not found, Ubuntu 24.04
I have Ubuntu 24.04 Noble, and was trying to build some old software.
The ./configure script returns:
configure: error: Package requirements (gtkgl-2.0) were not met:

Package 'gtkgl-2.0', required by 'virtual:world', not found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GTKGL_CFLAGS
and GTKGL_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.

Indeed, the readme says:

Install dependencies (Ubuntu): sudo apt-get install libgtkgl2.0-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev

However, apt returns an error, even after executing sudo apt update:
$ sudo apt-get install libgtkgl2.0-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev                                                                                                             

Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances... Fait
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait      
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet libgtkgl2.0-dev
E: Impossible de trouver de paquet correspondant à l'expression rationnelle « libgtkgl2.0-dev »
E: Impossible de trouver de paquet correspondant à l'expression rationnelle « libgtkgl2.0-dev »

Which translates to “unable to locate package libgtkgl2.0-dev” and “unable to locate package corresponding to regex libgtkgl2.0-dev”.
Note that sudo apt update executes without any error.
How can I install libgtkgl2.0-dev?

GTK2 is completely deprecated. Consider running a VM of an older version of Ubuntu (e.g. 20.04), or, port the software to a currently supported version of GTK (e.g. GTK3 or 4)
